# Hamburger menu "shakes" upon resizing the browser window

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, hamburger-menu

Upon resizing the browser window opposite the direction towards which the menu slides, you can clearly see it appearing and disappearing. It's like a "shaking" effect that shakes the menu out of its default position. On mobile you can slightly see it rotate while switching from portrait to landscape.

My CSS:

```
#menuSlideBox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
    background-color: var(--color-accent);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

#menuSlideBox.hidden {
    right: -80;
}
```

My JS:

```
const menuSlideShape = document.getElementById("menuSlideShape");

// GENERATES THE SLIDING MENU
const menuSlideBox = document.createElement("div");
menuSlideBox.id = "menuSlideBox";
menuSlideBox.style.transform = "translate(80vw)"; // Initially position the menu slide box outside the viewport

const closeMenu = document.createElement("button");
closeMenu.textContent = "Close";
closeMenu.id = "closeMenu";

menuSlideShape.addEventListener("click", function slideLeft() {
    menuSlideBox.style.transform = "translate(0)"; // Slide into view
});

closeMenu.addEventListener("click", function slideRight() {
    menuSlideBox.style.transform = "translate(80vw)"; // Slide out of view
});

document.body.appendChild(menuSlideBox);
menuSlideBox.appendChild(closeMenu);
```

I have replaced `transition: transform 0.3s ease`; with `right`, but that fixes the "shaking" while also removing the transition effect. There must be an easy way to fix this. With the current approach I can either hide the menu upon resizing, or keep the transition effect.